# Excel Index and match: using the index and match or Vlookup to return the second record and all associated column

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

```
Customer#   Date     Qty,   Cost 
 12       1/2/2013     3    500
 12       1/3/2013     5    200
 12       1/4/2013     4    200
 13       1/5/2013     1    150
 14       1/6/2013     2    110
 14       1/7/2013     1    110
 15       1/8/2013     1    110
```

I have a table similar to the above table (with millions of records and 26 column).I would like to create two table based of this one. the first table is to show me the first order of each customer and its associated column and the second one is to show me data for the second order of each customer ( if they don't have it will be null).

the Result i am looking for

Table one- First order

```
Customer#,  Date ,      Qty,  Cost 
 12 ,       1/2/2013,   3,    500
 13  ,      1/5/2013,   1,    150
 14   ,     1/6/2013,   2,    110
 15   ,     1/8/2013,   1,    110
```

Table two- second order  table

```
Customer#,  Date ,      Qty ,   Cost 
 12  ,      1/3/2013,   5,       200
 14 ,       1/7/2013,   1   ,    110
```

The formula i tried but failed to work

`=INDEX(B:D,MATCH(A3,A:A,0))`

I would appreciate if someone shares their ideas how to use the Index and match function in excel to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue above using Tableau. I just used the `Index()` function to calculate the rank based on their order date and id and filtered by the rank to get the first and second order table.